# Execution failed for task ':tunnel:buildCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a]'. - wireguard-android

Tags: android, wireguard

I am trying to run and build [wireguard-android](https://github.com/WireGuard/wireguard-android) project on Mac mini but getting following error:

Machine: Mac Mini

iOS Version: 12.6.3

go version go1.20.2 darwin/amd64

flock 0.4.0

```
Execution failed for task ':tunnel:buildCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a]'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: ninja: Entering directory `/Users/vinit/Desktop/wireguard/wireguard-android/tunnel/.cxx/Debug/2i1s1r74/arm64-v8a'
[1/15] Building wireguard-go
 FAILED: CMakeFiles/libwg-go.so /Users/vinit/Desktop/wireguard/wireguard-android/tunnel/.cxx/Debug/2i1s1r74/arm64-v8a/CMakeFiles/libwg-go.so 
 cd /Users/vinit/Desktop/wireguard/wireguard-android/tunnel/tools/libwg-go && make ANDROID_ARCH_NAME=arm64 ANDROID_PACKAGE_NAME=com.wireguard.android.debug GRADLE_USER_HOME=/Users/vinit/.gradle CC=/Users/vinit/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/23.1.7779620/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/clang "CFLAGS=-DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fexceptions" "LDFLAGS=-Wl,--build-id=sha1 -Wl,--no-rosegment -Wl,--fatal-warnings -Qunused-arguments -Wl,--no-undefined" SYSROOT=/Users/vinit/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/23.1.7779620/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/sysroot TARGET=aarch64-none-linux-android21 DESTDIR=/Users/vinit/Desktop/wireguard/wireguard-android/tunnel/build/intermediates/cxx/Debug/2i1s1r74/obj/arm64-v8a BUILDDIR=/Users/vinit/Desktop/wireguard/wireguard-android/tunnel/build/intermediates/cxx/Debug/2i1s1r74/obj/arm64-v8a/../generated-src
mkdir -p "/Users/vinit/.gradle/caches/golang/"
flock "/Users/vinit/.gradle/caches/golang/go1.20.2.darwin-amd64.tar.gz.lock" -c ' \
[ -f "/Users/vinit/.gradle/caches/golang/go1.20.2.darwin-amd64.tar.gz" ] && exit 0; \
curl -o "/Users/vinit/.gradle/caches/golang/go1.20.2.darwin-amd64.tar.gz.tmp" "https://dl.google.com/go/go1.20.2.darwin-amd64.tar.gz" && \
echo "c93b8ced9517d07e1cd4c362c6e2d5242cb139e29b417a328fbf19aded08764c  /Users/vinit/.gradle/caches/golang/go1.20.2.darwin-amd64.tar.gz.tmp" | sha256sum -c && \
mv "/Users/vinit/.gradle/caches/golang/go1.20.2.darwin-amd64.tar.gz.tmp" "/Users/vinit/.gradle/caches/golang/go1.20.2.darwin-amd64.tar.gz"'
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                               Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
2 95.4M    2 2335k    0     0  2840k      0  0:00:34 --:--:--  0:00:34 2905k
7 95.4M    7 7071k    0     0  3880k      0  0:00:25  0:00:01  0:00:24 3920k
—
96 95.4M   96 92.4M    0     0  4542k      0  0:00:21  0:00:20  0:00:01 4549k
100 95.4M  100 95.4M    0     0  4535k      0  0:00:21  0:00:21 --:--:-- 4602k
zsh:1: command not found: sha256sum
make: *** [/Users/vinit/.gradle/caches/golang/go1.20.2.darwin-amd64.tar.gz] Error 127
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':tunnel:buildCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a]'.
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$1(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:149)
at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:282)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:147)
—
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:49)
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: ninja: Entering directory `/Users/vinit/Desktop/wireguard/wireguard-android/tunnel/.cxx/Debug/2i1s1r74/arm64-v8a'
[1/15] Building wireguard-go
FAILED: CMakeFiles/libwg-go.so /Users/vinit/Desktop/wireguard/wireguard-android/tunnel/.cxx/Debug/2i1s1r74/arm64-v8a/CMakeFiles/libwg-go.so 
cd /Users/vinit/Desktop/wireguard/wireguard-android/tunnel/tools/libwg-go && make ANDROID_ARCH_NAME=arm64 ANDROID_PACKAGE_NAME=com.wireguard.android.debug GRADLE_USER_HOME=/Users/vinit/.gradle CC=/Users/vinit/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/23.1.7779620/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/clang "CFLAGS=-DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fexceptions" "LDFLAGS=-Wl,--build-id=sha1 -Wl,--no-rosegment -Wl,--fatal-warnings -Qunused-arguments -Wl,--no-undefined" SYSROOT=/Users/vinit/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/23.1.7779620/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/sysroot TARGET=aarch64-none-linux-android21 DESTDIR=/Users/vinit/Desktop/wireguard/wireguard-android/tunnel/build/intermediates/cxx/Debug/2i1s1r74/obj/arm64-v8a BUILDDIR=/Users/vinit/Desktop/wireguard/wireguard-android/tunnel/build/intermediates/cxx/Debug/2i1s1r74/obj/arm64-v8a/../generated-src
mkdir -p "/Users/vinit/.gradle/caches/golang/"
flock "/Users/vinit/.gradle/caches/golang/go1.20.2.darwin-amd64.tar.gz.lock" -c ' \
[ -f "/Users/vinit/.gradle/caches/golang/go1.20.2.darwin-amd64.tar.gz" ] && exit 0; \
curl -o "/Users/vinit/.gradle/caches/golang/go1.20.2.darwin-amd64.tar.gz.tmp" "https://dl.google.com/go/go1.20.2.darwin-amd64.tar.gz" && \
echo "c93b8ced9517d07e1cd4c362c6e2d5242cb139e29b417a328fbf19aded08764c  /Users/vinit/.gradle/caches/golang/go1.20.2.darwin-amd64.tar.gz.tmp" | sha256sum -c && \
mv "/Users/vinit/.gradle/caches/golang/go1.20.2.darwin-amd64.tar.gz.tmp" "/Users/vinit/.gradle/caches/golang/go1.20.2.darwin-amd64.tar.gz"'
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
2 95.4M    2 2335k    0     0  2840k      0  0:00:34 --:--:--  0:00:34 2905k
7 95.4M    7 7071k    0     0  3880k      0  0:00:25  0:00:01  0:00:24 3920k
11 95.4M   11 11.4M    0     0  4090k      0  0:00:23  0:00:02  0:00:21 4116k
—
100 95.4M  100 95.4M    0     0  4535k      0  0:00:21  0:00:21 --:--:-- 4602k
zsh:1: command not found: sha256sum
make: *** [/Users/vinit/.gradle/caches/golang/go1.20.2.darwin-amd64.tar.gz] Error 127
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

C++ build system [build] failed while executing:
/Users/vinit/Library/Android/sdk/cmake/3.22.1/bin/ninja \
  -C \
  /Users/vinit/Desktop/wireguard/wireguard-android/tunnel/.cxx/Debug/2i1s1r74/arm64-v8a \
  libwg-quick.so \
  libwg.so
 from /Users/vinit/Desktop/wireguard/wireguard-android/tunnel
at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:68)
at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:41)
—
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:49)
Caused by: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: ninja: Entering directory `/Users/vinit/Desktop/wireguard/wireguard-android/tunnel/.cxx/Debug/2i1s1r74/arm64-v8a'
[1/15] Building wireguard-go
FAILED: CMakeFiles/libwg-go.so /Users/vinit/Desktop/wireguard/wireguard-android/tunnel/.cxx/Debug/2i1s1r74/arm64-v8a/CMakeFiles/libwg-go.so 
cd /Users/vinit/Desktop/wireguard/wireguard-android/tunnel/tools/libwg-go && make ANDROID_ARCH_NAME=arm64 ANDROID_PACKAGE_NAME=com.wireguard.android.debug GRADLE_USER_HOME=/Users/vinit/.gradle CC=/Users/vinit/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/23.1.7779620/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/clang "CFLAGS=-DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fexceptions" "LDFLAGS=-Wl,--build-id=sha1 -Wl,--no-rosegment -Wl,--fatal-warnings -Qunused-arguments -Wl,--no-undefined" SYSROOT=/Users/vinit/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/23.1.7779620/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/sysroot TARGET=aarch64-none-linux-android21 DESTDIR=/Users/vinit/Desktop/wireguard/wireguard-android/tunnel/build/intermediates/cxx/Debug/2i1s1r74/obj/arm64-v8a BUILDDIR=/Users/vinit/Desktop/wireguard/wireguard-android/tunnel/build/intermediates/cxx/Debug/2i1s1r74/obj/arm64-v8a/../generated-src
mkdir -p "/Users/vinit/.gradle/caches/golang/"
flock "/Users/vinit/.gradle/caches/golang/go1.20.2.darwin-amd64.tar.gz.lock" -c ' \
[ -f "/Users/vinit/.gradle/caches/golang/go1.20.2.darwin-amd64.tar.gz" ] && exit 0; \
curl -o "/Users/vinit/.gradle/caches/golang/go1.20.2.darwin-amd64.tar.gz.tmp" "https://dl.google.com/go/go1.20.2.darwin-amd64.tar.gz" && \
echo "c93b8ced9517d07e1cd4c362c6e2d5242cb139e29b417a328fbf19aded08764c  /Users/vinit/.gradle/caches/golang/go1.20.2.darwin-amd64.tar.gz.tmp" | sha256sum -c && \
mv "/Users/vinit/.gradle/caches/golang/go1.20.2.darwin-amd64.tar.gz.tmp" "/Users/vinit/.gradle/caches/golang/go1.20.2.darwin-amd64.tar.gz"'
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
2 95.4M    2 2335k    0     0  2840k      0  0:00:34 --:--:--  0:00:34 2905k
7 95.4M    7 7071k    0     0  3880k      0  0:00:25  0:00:01  0:00:24 3920k
11 95.4M   11 11.4M    0     0  4090k      0  0:00:23  0:00:02  0:00:21 4116k
—-
96 95.4M   96 92.4M    0     0  4542k      0  0:00:21  0:00:20  0:00:01 4549k
100 95.4M  100 95.4M    0     0  4535k      0  0:00:21  0:00:21 --:--:-- 4602k
zsh:1: command not found: sha256sum
make: *** [/Users/vinit/.gradle/caches/golang/go1.20.2.darwin-amd64.tar.gz] Error 127
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

C++ build system [build] failed while executing:
/Users/vinit/Library/Android/sdk/cmake/3.22.1/bin/ninja \
  -C \
  /Users/vinit/Desktop/wireguard/wireguard-android/tunnel/.cxx/Debug/2i1s1r74/arm64-v8a \
  libwg-quick.so \
  libwg.so
from /Users/vinit/Desktop/wireguard/wireguard-android/tunnel
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.cxx.process.ExecuteProcessKt.execute(ExecuteProcess.kt:274)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.cxx.process.ExecuteProcessKt$executeProcess$1.invoke(ExecuteProcess.kt:106)
—
at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:125)
... 113 more
Caused by: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing process /Users/vinit/Library/Android/sdk/cmake/3.22.1/bin/ninja with arguments {-C /Users/vinit/Desktop/wireguard/wireguard-android/tunnel/.cxx/Debug/2i1s1r74/arm64-v8a libwg-quick.so libwg.so}
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.buildProcessException(GradleProcessResult.java:73)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.assertNormalExitValue(GradleProcessResult.java:48)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.cxx.process.ExecuteProcessKt.execute(ExecuteProcess.kt:269)
... 130 more
Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Users/vinit/Library/Android/sdk/cmake/3.22.1/bin/ninja'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:415)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.assertNormalExitValue(GradleProcessResult.java:46)
... 131 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note this error `zsh:1: command not found: sha256sum`
You can fix this problem by `brew install coreutils`